# How to configure datasource for keycloak to work well with galera cluster?

Tags: jdbc, jboss, wildfly, keycloak, galera

### ENV:

**Linux:** Red Hat 7.5 (Maipo)

**MariaDB:** 10.2.13-MariaDB

**Keycloak:** 3.4.3.Fina

**JDBC driver:** mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar

### Decription:

I start a keycloak instance , make it to connect to a galera-cluster.

**while :**

**If I** use “kill -9 mariaDB process” on a gelera node, the connection between keycloak and galera will occurred 500 error, after few seconds, 200 OK go on.

**If I** use “kill -15 mariaDB process” on a gelera node, the connection between keycloak and galera will 200 OK go on, no error happened.

"kill -9" to simulate the crash scenario for mysql service.

**what I hope is that no any error when mysql service crashed. (e.g kill -9), keycloak should auto connect to next galera node when current node is crashed , without any errors**

Below is my datasource configuration in standalone.xml

---

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
<connection-url>jdbc:mariadb:failover://db1,db2,db3/keycloak?autoReconnect=true&amp</connection-url>
   <driver>mariadb</driver>
   <security>
      <user-name>kc_dbuser</user-name>
      <password>7a092075c015090fe21c83ecd6f6</password>
   </security>
   <pool>
      <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
      <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
   </pool>
   <validation>
      <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
      <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
      <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
      <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
      <background-validation>true</background-validation>
      <background-validation-millis>1000</background-validation-millis>
      <use-fast-fail>true</use-fast-fail>
   </validation>
   <statement>
      <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
   </statement>
</datasource>
```

is a keycloak bug or JBOSS bug or JDBC driver BUG or just configuration problem ?
**How to resolve it?**

Answer (score 0):

Change Line No 2 With This Code

```
<connection-url>jdbc:mariadb:failover://db1,db2,db3/keycloak?autoReconnect=true</connection-url>
```